# Failing reasons for executeUpdate("INSERT...");

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am writing a program in Java to insert a bunch of information to my MySQL DB, and need to track the number and reason of failures. I understand `executeUpdate()` will return the number of rows that were affected by the SQL statement.

```
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT/UPDATE...");
```

My question is, if the return value is 0 (no exception in this case), is there a way to find the possible reasons that cause the `INSERT/UPDATE` to not work?

Comment: If the UPDATE won't fail, the only possibility for returning 0 results is if the records aren't found. For INSERT i cannot think of a situation.

Comment: Consider enabling error logging on the mysql database.  It will contain a list of failures with a (sometimes cryptic) description of the cause.

Answer (score 2):

For UPDATE, a return value of 0 is obvious: no rows updated.
For INSERT, the only situation I can think of is when you try to perform an INSERT SELECT (...) and the result of the SELECT contains 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it did not fail. Zero stands for no change. 
I see two ways to get more information.

1. use stmt.execute() which returns false then check the integer value. if it is -1, then there was result at all which is a bad sign.
2. Use Result set for the insert/update/delete operations. But you need to retrieve the exact data you would like to update/.....

Note: Had an exception been thrown, you would have gotten a more friendly message in the catch block, exc.getMessage()